# How do I access microk8s externally exposed service ip over network?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, microk8s

I am running a microk8s instance on Ubuntu server as a vanilla install, configured with MetalLB to dynamically allocate 10.0.2.1 to 10.0.2.200 and the Nginx ingress controller enabled. I've installed the wordpress helm chart on this instance (https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/wordpress/#installing-the-chart) with the following command:

```bsh
helm install wordpress \
  --set wordpressUsername=admin \
  --set wordpressPassword=password \
  --set mariadb.mariadbRootPassword=secretpassword \
  --set ingress.enabled=true \
  --set ingress.hostname=wordpress.internal \
    bitnami/wordpress
```

Service is up and running successfully, and when I run

```bsh
kubectl describe services wordpress
```

I get the following:

```bsh
Name:                     wordpress
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=wordpress
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=wordpress
                          helm.sh/chart=wordpress-9.3.10
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: wordpress
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/instance=wordpress,app.kubernetes.io/name=wordpress
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.152.183.73
LoadBalancer Ingress:     10.0.2.1
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31799/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.70.14:8080
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  30087/TCP
Endpoints:                10.1.70.14:8443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason        Age                  From                Message
  ----    ------        ----                 ----                -------
  Normal  IPAllocated   32m                  metallb-controller  Assigned IP "10.0.2.1"
  Normal  nodeAssigned  6m41s (x3 over 31m)  metallb-speaker     announcing from node "k8s"
```

When I am SSH'ed onto the node where microk8s is installed, the instance responds as I would expect:

```bsh
curl 10.0.2.1

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js" lang="en-US">

    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >

        <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

        <title>User&#039;s Blog! &#8211; Just another WordPress site</title>
```

However, when I run the same command over my networked Macbook, I'm unable to get a response:

```bsh
curl 10.0.2.1

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.2.1 port 80: Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After noting that the following two methodologies worked:

1. Access via portforward (navigate to localhost:8080 in browser with below command)

```bsh
kubectl port-forward *podname-here* 8080:8080
```

2. NodePort (navigating to browser at *k8s-master-ip*:31799)

I isolated the issue to the IP range I had allocated to metallb. The problem was that I had allocated an IP range to metallb (10.0.2.1-10.0.2.200) that was outside of the subnet mask configured in my consumer router (Apple Airport Extreme). Once I changed the IP range to one within the subnet allowed by the router (10.0.1.100-10.0.1.150), navigation to the service IP worked as expected.