# How to expose my Minikube tunnel network (LoadBalancer) to my Wifi / LAN

Tags: networking, kubernetes, minikube

I am using Minikube in a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS for development of a Kubernetes solution (using Docker for virtualization). I use "minikube tunnel" command to have LoadBalancer service get an IP as without it it will never get one assigned, but that IP is internal for the docker/minikube virtual network. Service details:

```
vault         service/vault-ui         LoadBalancer   10.104.96.77    10.104.96.77   20001:31379/TCP          13s
```

My Linux box is connected to my Wifi (let's say, IP 192.168.0.114) on interface wlp2s0.

How can I make visible that LoadBalancer visible in my local Wifi network? (I have no intentions to expose it to Internet... just to be able to access the LoadBalancer from my desktop Mac in the same Wifi network)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access microk8s externally exposed service ip over network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248327/how-do-i-access-microk8s-externally-exposed-service-ip-over-network)

Comment: Thanks but I don't believe so... the solutions describe how to access through localhost, but I need to access the LoadBalancer from my mavbook in my local network (Wifi interface... Ethernet interface could work as I don't mind cabling my MacBook to the server via Ethernet).

Comment: Hello again... I've found a solution very similar to the one in that link. I found it somewhere else but it's true it is related... not directly exposing a pod but a service. I'll add it here. Thanks again for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The following command exposed the LoadBalancer:

```
kubectl port-forward --address=0.0.0.0 service/vault-ui 20001:20001 --namespace vault
```

I would like to have a configurable solution but given I need this for development it's more than valid.